# How to store and query by schedules in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've done some research and found [Ice Cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube), but it stores the schedule as YAML in a `TEXT` SQL type column.

The goal is to find something that is standard as far as storing schedules and allows, for example, a query interface for "all records where the schedule includes `TODAY()`".

It seems this is a **hard** problem, and [the leading solution (that I could find) is to create an `occurrences` table](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/issues/175).  If there's no end time to the schedule, then you have to make a decision as to how many occurrences to store.  Are there any best practices here?

Comment: I'm not aware of any generic solution. The question is how flexible your querying needs to be and how complex your schedules are allowed to become. If you can narrow down your use cases, it might be possible to build something based on the [OpenStreetMap opening hours](wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours) format using some clever regex matchers.

Comment: can you get this done with a worker ?

Comment: @ma_il We'd really like the same flexibility as Google Calendar.  The goal would be to build something like http://recurring-select-demo.herokuapp.com/.  But the challenge for me has been not implementing the store (in that case), it's supporting the query (absent an `occurrences` table/object).

Comment: @Thounder I don't think so?  I'm not quite sure what you mean.  For example, say you have a subscription and you want to tell people the exact dates their subscription will trigger.

Comment: What do you want to tell? Send a yearly mail?

Comment: No, it's to power a dashboard.  We have a few things that depend on schedules (i.e. recurring invoices, reports, billing cycles, etc.).  It's important that we can show at least the next schedule date/time (which is the easy problem), but most customers want to know _all_ of them, which clearly isn't possible without saying "all up to a year away."